# Converting xlA1 Formula to xlR1C1 gives error

Tags: excel, vba

All of my formulas are converting without any issues it's just these following two formulas are giving me an error when I try to convert them to R1C1. Can someone please advise why is this happening ?

```
"=IF(Control!$B$116=1,"",IF(A24="","",IF('Sub Lot Input'!$L$25="","",IF(OR('Calcs - Conversion'!DJ9="",'Calcs - Conversion'!DJ9="-"),"-",IF(OR(Other_Analysis_Input_Field=4,Other_Analysis_Input_Field=5),MROUND('Calcs - Conversion'!DJ9,'Calcs - Conversion'!$AC$66),'Calcs - Conversion'!DJ9)))))"

"=IF(OR('Control'!$B$235=TRUE,'Control'!$B$236=TRUE),IF('Additional Analysis Input'!$C$14="","Degree C.",'Additional Analysis Input'!$C$14),"")"
```

I am converting the formula to R1C1 using the following line of code:

```
Formula = Application.ConvertFormula( _
                                    Formula:=wk_sht.Range(cell).Formula, _
                                    fromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                                    toReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

I am getting type mismatch error.

Comment: According to the documentation, "There is a 255 character limit for the formula" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.convertformula), and the length of the first formula is 292 characters

Comment: What about the second one ?

Comment: I had the second formula converted fine. Perhaps the error could be in the argument `wk_sht.Range(cell)`.

Comment: I am getting type mismatch error. The arguments are all correct I have tested. There is one thing that I noticed when I printed `wk_sht.Range(cell).FormulaHidden`, it returns True. Do you think that can be an issue ?

Comment: I don't think this could be the source of the error, because `.FormulaHidden` specifies whether the formula will be hidden when the worksheet is protected. On the other hand, if 1) the formula is in the cell, 2) it is correct by itself, then you can do without `.ConvertFormula` and use `Formula = wk_sht.Range(cell).FormulaR1C1`.